# Check if byte is 0xFF in Perl

Tags: perl

I would like to check if a byte in Perl is set to 0xFF.

I can do this to check it now:

```
unpack('C', $byte) == 255
```

But it seems like that wouldn't be the correct or most efficient way of doing this. Is there a shorthand notation for checking this that might be faster?

Comment: It's a single 8-bit byte. The byte itself is 11111111 in binary.

Comment: I guess I'm very confused then. The data in $byte is a byte sent to me from a client connection. That connection could send me anything in that byte. I want to check if that byte is 0xFF, because the protocol states that particular value for a byte terminates a message. I don't know how to better indicate that a variable contains a single byte than to name it $byte. Can you please give me an example of how I could better show exactly what's in $byte?

Comment: What’s a byte? How do you know you have one? Where did you get it? Perl can only check code points, not “bytes”, because the notion doesn’t make sense.  You have a character.  If its code point is under 0x100, does that make it a byte in your eyes? Hm. I guess calling `sysread` on a `:raw` filehandle for a length of 1 would get you a byte, but gosh! There’s some mental-model failure going on here for the question even to be asked.

Comment: Well as you asked, I did a sysread on a socket for 1 byte. So-- yeah. In the particular protocol I'm dealing with, a message is wrapped in a starting byte (0x00) and a closing byte (0xFF). I go through these byte by byte (character by character), for each character between 0x00 and 0xFF. In my actual code there is no $byte at all, but rather a substring. I felt like $byte would make it more clear what I was referring to, but it appears to have done the opposite. I wasn't being intentionally cryptic, but rather simple to avoid confusion (that didn't work).

Comment: @SinanÜnür , characters and integers in Perl don't work like they do in C.  In Perl, if you have a single "\xFF" in a scalar, it's numerically equal to zero, not to 255.  So doing `$byte == 255` is not appropriate.

Comment: @KenWilliams When my original comment was made, the OP had not posted the explanatory comment. Cleaned up. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about simple?

```
if ($byte eq "\xff") { ... }
```

Comment: I was kind of hoping there was a way to do it that didn't involve Perl interpreting a string. I have a feeling that this is probably slower than unpack, but I'll check.

Comment: @GoldenNewby: this is absolutely the correct way to do what you ask. I don't know what you mean by *interpreting a string*. This code simply compares two one-character strings for equality.

Comment: @Borodin: Thanks for fixing. It is too late here ;-)

Comment: It is funny that absolute newbies and greenhorns are most concerned about the "speed" of low level operations .....

Comment: It's because they lack (1) the knowledge needed to profile, (2) the foundation necessary to select the best algorithm for the task at hand, and (3) the confidence to just code for clarity and worry about optimization when it proves necessary.

Comment: (1) I could profile the different algorithms, but I'd need to know what my options were (2) Same thing, I only knew the unpack method, that's why I asked (3) I was asking for my own curiosity, not out of a lack of confidence. My example in my question worked to begin with.

Comment: I think he somehow has a brainbug with his mental model of character data in Perl, but I’m not sure where the failure lies.

Comment: @GoldenNewby, How can you ask not to involve string operations if your input is a string?

Comment: @GoldenNewby: this is the fastest way to do your comparison, much faster than `unpack`. A simple `ord $byte == 0xFF` would have been (much) faster than `unpack` as well, but the string comparison proposed by @Borodin is even faster.

Comment: The solution was from @Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil, sorry!

Comment: @emazep Yeah I realise that now. My original comment on this post was misguided, I was running out the door at the time and was mis-thinking. This was actually the solution I came to in the past, but I had lost it.

Comment: @Ingo - *everyone* is concerned about efficiency.  Newbies just don't know enough to know which things are slick, and which things are horrible, so they ask questions.  Trying to learn something is a *good* thing.

Comment: @KenWilliams Absolutely. That's why we should teach them the mantra: "Make it right, then make it fast." and, by "make if fast", we mean foremost: use a good algorithm. Concerns about efficiency are okay, obsession with microseconds is different.